# Find all Ring homomorphisms of $f: \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Could you please tell me whether my proof is correct or not,

$f(x)=f(x.1)=f(x).f(1)$ (Since we are finding ring homomorphism and unity belongs to set of Rationals, assuming f as ring homomorphism)

from above it is clear that $f(1)$ is unity element.

also $f(x) = f(1+1+1+1+.....+$x times) $=f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+.......+f(1) = x . f(1)$

or

$f(x) . f(1)= x . f(1) $

$f(1)(f(x)-x)=0$ (since Q is intergral domain, we get two cases)

$f(1) = 0$ corresponds to zero homomorphism

and $f(x) = x$ corresponds to Identity homomorphism

Thus we get only two ring homomorphisms from $f: \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$

Comment: $f(x) = f(1+1+\cdots+1)$ only holds for $x \in \mathbb N^*$.

Comment: so I can't use that to prove the above result for Rational Numbers? but just one doubt, why am i still getting the required results using $f(x) = f(1+1+...+1)$

Comment: @RohitBharadwaj: $\forall \: m\in\mathbb{Q}\quad f(x)=f\left(m\cdot\dfrac xm\right)=m\cdot f\left(\dfrac xm\right)=f(m)\cdot  f\left(\dfrac xm\right)\implies f\left(\dfrac xm\right)=0 $ or $f(m)=m$.

Comment: @RohitBharadwaj No, that's not what I meant. I mean your reasoning just shows the possible conclusions for $x \in \mathbb N^*$, not necessarily applicable to all $x \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @RohitBharadwaj: The two ring homomorphism are $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=0$.